# MANOVA shows significant main effects only but ANOVA shows both main and interaction effects

Tags: anova, manova

I have five DVs that are correlated, so I ran a 2x2 MANOVA, which showed a significant main effect. But follow-up univariate ANOVA with one of the DVs showed both a main and an interaction effect. Should I discard the interaction effect since MANOVA says it is not significant?